# How to fix this animation using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am using JQuery to make a 'Read More' button. When someone clicks onthe button a popup appears. This popup is actually a hidden div that appears. My problem is that while I click the button I want the div to appear from the button and when I click the cross mark on the popup it sould go back to the same button where it originated from but the result that I am getting is, when I click on the button the div appears from it whereas when I click cross it goes to the 'read more' button which I clicked the first. Please help me fix this. I guess there is a small glitch in my code. I have it on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/qLEbD/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6uLF7/

The problem was with the local scope of the variables that store the target left and top offsets.

**CHANGES**

Added 2 declarations at the top:

```
var readMoreInfoTop = 0;
var readMoreInfoLeft = 0;
```

Removed `var` keyword from the `top` and `left` assignments inside the `click` handler

```
readMoreInfoTop = readMoreOffset.top + 10;
readMoreInfoLeft = readMoreOffset.left + 10;
```

Comment: +1 for perfect solution; will u please point out the changes in line in you fiddle??

Comment: @techfoobar actually the best solution is to remove the $('.cross').click event from the readmoreinfo block and mention it separately and then declare the two variables global for both of the click events... global only wrt the 2 click events. You can have a look here  http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/qLEbD/

Comment: @techfoobar thanks for your help it was useful to figure out the scope thing. :)

Comment: +1 Yes, that is indeed the cleanest solution (avoiding globals as much as possible).

Answer (score 0):

Each time you open a button, you are adding another listener to the close button. You could unbind the close listener before rebinding it eg. http://jsfiddle.net/qLEbD/54/

or better yet...

bind the close listener once (outside the button click function) and store the left position on button click eg.

```
//doc ready...
function() {

  var leftPosition;

  $('.button').click(function() {
    //animate popup to open
    leftPosition = $(this).offset.left;
  });

  $('#close').click(function() {
    //animate popup to close using leftPosition
  });
}();
```

Comment: I got that but it would not be wise to avoid an error which is there.. this is just a fix. Thanks though. I have changes the thing in http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/qLEbD/ please check it.